# How best to make a clip of a burning house?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation, physics, tracking

I plan to make a clip of a burning house in Blender. My objective is to make this photorealistic as possible. Now I think I can model the house and its environment (including the right materials and textures) and set it on fire and make an animation of that.

But recently I had some first experience with the movie clip editor and the camera tracking possibilities of Blender. And now I think maybe you could also make a movie of a house (with a camera) and also make an animation of a 3D model on fire and integrate the original movie and the Blender made animation.

So my question is what would be the best approach. Either the "modelling approach" or the "VFX approach" ??? The house should be a typical "american suburban house".

I hope that this is not a subjective question. If it is, maybe some people are willing to give me some advice in the chat room ?

Comment: I feel it a bit subjective... but if "as photorealistic as possible", there could be a third option : a movie of a burning house : )

Comment: if this is subjective I will delete the question. I thought a really skilled Blender artist knows if both options are feasible and which way would be best to go. It is a very challenging project for me and I would be very helped by an answer of a skiled artist

Comment: No no, don't delete it : I have no real opinion about that

Comment: You are in for a very complex endeavor...  photorealistic...  Either one of your proposed approaches would work. Know that you are going to have to spend a lot of time on either of them. Creating everything as CG will give you absolute control, but you'll find out soon enough how many details need to be taken care of to sell something as "real". Starting with a film clip would ease the pain of creating everything, but integrating the CG elements will also be labor intensive: recreaitng interactive lighting, heat distortion, and shadowing...

Comment: A better asnwer for this would be on a forum for special FX, in my opinion...

Comment: people say that you really learn something if you work on a real project, not only tutorials. This is a project that I really would like to do, probably very challenging but I will also learn an awful lot

Comment: I like @lemon 's approach the best. Film the real thing!

Comment: @cegaton your are off-topic, that is not a Blender solution ;)

Comment: @cegaton So you you feel the movie clip approach (VFX approach) is feasible. Would I need other software next to Blender ? And uhh... can you recommend any VFX forums ?

Comment: Camera tracking can be tricky. You can use [After](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el_n1UfPL_M) [Effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBWHSi-ZMWM) to create tracking helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't try to use CG on top of real footage

It would be much harder to burn down footage of a house then to simulate a burning house.

### Best case scenerio

Using real footage and trying to simulate fire on top if it is a very bad idea, however, the best option is obviously to find an abandoned house and burn it down whilst recording it with several nice cameras.

The low budget alternative is to craft a 1/100th scale house, or any house that is much smaller, but with similar materials and film using several cameras.

### If you don't have fancy cameras

If you would rather spend time on the computer, rather than in a woodworking shop or behind fancy cameras, you could model the house in blender, create realistic materials, and use a fire simulation in blender.

Comment: I am now walking the path of spending time on the computer :) It REALLY stretches my Blender skills and I hope these skills and resulting assets are re-usable

Answer (score 2):

Feasible to do this on footage, with caveats. A few quick and ridiculous thoughts:

- A pretty decent estimation of the scene referred transform for your footage. Absolutely mandatory, otherwise it is the nasty After Effects Hacks-All-The-Way-Down approach.
- Good deal of reference photos of the house in question. You'd be needing these for the texturing, lighting, and supplementing the geometry I'd suspect.
- A *very* compelling fire sim.

If the goal is absolute mimesis, most should be able to deduce that using photogrammetry techniques coupled with real footage is going to be infinitely more plausible than any from-scratch approach.

That said, no easy task by a long shot, but likely *only* feasible using real world footage coupled with CGI.

Comment: I am now walking the from-scratch route. But these two words - mimesis and photogrammetry - trigger some new learnings. Thanks